# Is there a way to create Blazor components documentation from the parameter's comments?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-client-side, asp.net-blazor

With swagger, you can automatically create documentation of your API methods based on the comments.

Is it possible to do the same, but for Blazor components?

Comment: Asking for libraries is specifically off-topic on Stack Overflow, so I removed that question. Asking if it is possible is on-topic, and people can answer with libraries if they know about them. You may wish to update your question with any research you've done to avoid downvotes, but of course that's optional.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thanks, I have searched, but I couldn't find a way to do it. Every time I type Blazor with the word documentation or docs, I just end up in the lblazor docs

Answer (score 6):

If you are referring to the parameters for a Blazor component and you are wanting documentation (i.e. intellisense summary) then yes. In Visual Studio if you structure the code as follows it should show up when users reference the parameter from another Blazor component.

```
/// <summary>
/// Here is the description of the parameter InputValue and what it is used for
/// </summary>
[Parameter]
public string InputValue { get; set; }
```

In Visual Studio if you type `///` it should auto-generate the format for you.

Comment: But will the documentation pass through via swagger? That was the OP's question.

Comment: Swagger is a system for documenting an API - these are normally created from controllers and methods. Blazor components are totally unrelated to Swagger and APIs, and would never be called from an external site. Two different concepts entirely